# Angularjs empty dropdown with ngModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi in my controller I am assigning following value

Than in html dropdown I have,

```
<div n-repeat="a in area">
  <select ng-options="" ng-model="area.location" ></select>
<div>
```

Basically I want to show dropdown and only have one value selected which is area.location.
I tried it with empty ng-options or no ng-options it doesn't work. 
Due to the way same field works in other section I cant use span or input to show this value has to show in a dropdown. 
Please let me know how I can show just on value from ng-model as selected in dropdown.
Thanks

Comment: What does your `area` look like? You repeat area with `a in area` but then you use `area.location`. Maybe it should be `a.location`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues on your code:
First, if you want the  tag to repeat, you should put the ng-repeat directive on the  tag.
Second, you shouldn't use both ng-repeat and ng-options, You'll just get a wrong result.
Third, when you use the ng-repeat at this form nh-repeat="a in area", the a is the single item. so write ng-model ="a.location" instead of area.location.
area is the array, which probably doesn't have the property "location"

Hope this is what you need:

```
<select ng-model="selectedArea" ng-options="a.location for a in area">     
</select>
```